# Numpy 'logical and' producing different type list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logical-operators

I am doing a logical operation on a data frame column data using NumPy. I am checking if a row value is less than two compared to the preceding and successful row. I am getting output but different than what I expected

```
ad = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,4,6,7,5,9,10]})
op=np.array(np.logical_and.reduce([ad['a'].\
                       diff(x).abs().le(2) for x in [1,-1]]))
print(op)
```

Present output:

```
[False  True  True  True  True False False False]
```

Expected output:

```
[False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  The values?  or the display style?  `np.logical_and` will return an array, so you don't need the extra `np.array` wrapper.  Are you just displaying the array/list, or are you going add it to a dataframe (as a column)?

Comment: @hpaulj you got it right. I will add it back to the data frame as a new column.

Comment: then you don't need to convert it to a list.  the array form will work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`numpy.ndarray.tolist`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy-ndarray-tolist) to convert the array to a list.

##### `>>> op.tolist()`

```
[False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just how the output for printing Numpy Arrays look. If you truly want the comma separated print output then you can just cast the original array as a list.  otherwise these two outputs you've presented are the same

'''

```
ad = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,4,6,7,5,9,10]})
op=np.array(np.logical_and.reduce([ad['a'].\
                   diff(x).abs().le(2) for x in [1,-1]]))
print(op)  
op = list(op)
print(op)
```

''''

output:

- before list

> [False  True  True  True  True False False False]

- after list

> [False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False]